# apple push notification feedback service - i can not get anything from the feedback service

Tags: ios, push, feedback

when I connect to the feedback service, it can successfully connected, but i get nothing from the feedback service.

i have uninstall the app from my device, and push again, and then connect to feedback service, but i still get nothing, even the next day.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

> If you remove your app from your device or computer and then send a
>   push notification to it, you would expect to have the device token
>   rejected, and the invalidated device token should appear on the
>   feedback service. However, if this was the last push-enabled app on
>   the device or computer, it will not show up in the feedback service.
>   This is because deleting the last app tears down the persistent
>   connection to the push service before the notice of the deletion can
>   be sent.
>
> You can work around this by leaving at least one push-enabled app on
>   the device or computer in order to keep the persistent connection up.
>   To keep the persistent connection to the production environment up,
>   just install any free push-enabled app from the App Store and you
>   should then be able to delete your app and see it appear in the
>   feedback service.
>
> Recall that each push environment has its own persistent connection.
>   So to keep the persistent connection to the sandbox environment up,
>   install another development push-enabled app.

source: [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

So just install any push-enabled app from the app-store after uninstalling your own app and your devicetoken should be triggered by the Feedback-Service.

Pay attention to the certificate & environment you are using (sandbox/production). Also keep in mind that the Feedback-Service only list failed delivery-attempts from your last push.